# Single vs. Dual Sockets In Network Programming

Tags: sockets, network-programming

The question is about network programming, more precisely servers. Let's suppose there is a server which handles a lot of connections, and thus has a listening socket. There obviously exists a single instance of such a socket, that's clear. Now I've seen designs which use (a)one socket for every connection, both for incoming and outgoing data, and (b)two sockets, one for the incoming data, one for the outgoing data. What makes one or the other design more preferrable? What are the possible reasons / usecases for these two designs?
The programs I was referring to were actually instant messengers (two of them), but this theoretically applies to any multiple-connection server (any server, then.)

Hope this question is not too generic, I don't know a lot about network programming at the moment, so asking this. Rapid Googling didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP and UDP Sockets are full duplex. There is no reason whatsoever to use separate sockets for input from and output to the same client. It is just wastefully using up kernel resources at double the rate.

Comment: OK, so as far as I can see, that design (with dual sockets) was flawed since the very beginning, right? Or could they have done like that because of connection recovery in the case of connection loss? Still, thanks for the explanation, it has shown me what direction I should investigate further as far as TCP sockets are concerned (duplex is the keyword here).

Comment: @Semen Semenych: Using two sockets where one would suffice doesn't help connection recovery in any way that I can see. It only introduces the additional complication that now one of the connections may be down and the other one still up.